# jQuery Explode changes fonts while exploding, how do I stop this?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, explode, jquery-effects

Go to http://hartford.uconn.edu/scholarships/ click on any name, then click on "close" button which will show you that while "exploding" the fonts change from default "Trebuchet MS/ Trebuchet" to "Times New Roman". I have tried defining body {font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Trebuchet;} and defining other classes and change jQuery widget classes as well to define desired font family but nothing seems to work. Please take a look at source and any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, the "explode" effect is actually creating several clones of whatever is being animated and applying the effects to those. These clones are attached to the end of the root `<body>` element. It looks like your CSS has the `font-family` defined on the `#center_wrapper` div, which doesn't apply to the clones, so they're shown as default unstyled text.

Defining the font on `body` instead worked for me. Perhaps your browser was caching the old CSS?

Comment: Same here, I copied the `font-family` and `font-size` rules to the body element (via FireBug) and it worked as expected.